# Save dialog box freezes during loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA program that pulls data from a network location, processes the data, and then saves it as a single CSV file.  This loop will create over a 1000 separate CSV files.

The error that I get is that seemingly at random, the saving dialog box will just get stuck.  It's like it's saving the file, but never completes, and will sit there indefinitely.  If I hit cancel, the macro just proceeds. (I blacked out the file name)

[image]

My code for this is:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

counter = 2
Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Production_Data").Cells(Counter, 5).Value = ""

    '''' Main operations go here ''''

    'Save workbook to new file

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'move worksheet to new workbook
    Set newbook = Workbooks.Add(1) 'create new workbook object with only 1 sheet
    newbook.Sheets(1).Name = "toDelete" 'name the worksheet

    ws.Activate 'activate the temporary worksheet to be moved
    Sheets(tempSheetName).Move Before:=newbook.Sheets(1)

    newbook.Sheets("toDelete").Delete 'remove the blank sheet created in new workbook

    'save as CSV file
    fname = destPath & "/" & tempSheetName & ".csv"
    newbook.SaveAs FileName:=fname, FileFormat:=xlCSV
    newbook.Close

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

counter = counter + 1
loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Is there any way to automatically exit this "frozen" dialog box and continue the macro?  Is there something wrong with my code?  Ideally this could be avoided all together.

The only other idea I've had is that my excel book with the macro is on a network drive, and maybe somehow that gets it to freeze up somehow?

---

edit

I tried adding `set newbook = Nothing` after closing it, but it still remains open in the VBA Project manager.

Comment: ...where's the loop?

Comment: Probably not actually freezing, but just taking an extremly long time to execute. For sure you can add "application.screenupdating=false" and "application.calculation=xlCalculationManual" to remove some of the overhead.
Also - since you don't destroy your newbook object, I'd advise to add "set newbook = nothing" after the close statement.
Lastly - have a look at this thread on MSDN social: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c11b360e-a1a8-4429-923d-89253371cc3d/excel-2010-crash-when-saving-file-with-vba-code?forum=exceldev

Comment: I copied this from within my loop... I added in what is representative of the loop

Comment: Thanks Rik.  I left it running last night and in the morning it had been locked on the same file for 8 hours...  I also do have "application.screenupdating=False".  It's a good point about destroying the newbook object, it's probably creating a lot of overhead like you say, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Wait - you never iterate `Counter`, so it's going to be an infinite loop, no?  I think you need a `Counter = Counter + 1` before `loop`...

Comment: The loop scans down the worksheet until there is no more data; when it reaches a blank row, the loop is over.  Each row represents a separate iteration of my loop.  It's not the best designed loop, but it works.

Comment: It *does* loop?? Where is `Counter` declared, and increased by one? Unless I'm overlooking something (which certainly is possible), I think your loop will just stay in the same cell, no? What happens to `Counter` when you use `F8` and go into a second and third loop?

Comment: I updated the code to reflect the counter increase.  I only copied to this post the section of my code where the problem is occurring.

Comment: @RikSportel I tried `set newbook = Nothing` but it still remains open in the VBA project manager.

Comment: Not an answer... But may be this is a memory / network issue.. can you check the memory usage of the computer during this process... you can do this using Task Manager...  Or try saving the files locally first...

Comment: I suspect you are saving the csv files ot a network folder. Try saving them to a local folder first, then use explorer to copy them to the network.